# Aspect annotation links

Tags: java, maven, aspectj, aop

New to aspect oriented development.

Two part question coming up.

1. Do you have any good sites that contain tutorial and code that runs? 
   So far i have seen many tutorials but with fragmented code and there is nothing that i can piece together so that it works locally.
2. Im trying to create a framework with an aspect and a aspectj class that should intercept all the method calls that are annotated with the aspect. 
   It works great in my local project but when i try to use the aspect in another project it does not seem to be working.

Code example: Aspect interceptor

```
@Aspect
public class InterceptCallAspect {
    @Around("execution(* *(@InterceptCall (*)));")
    public void record(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //Before
        System.out.println("Before");
        proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("After");
        //After
    }
}
```

The Aspect

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface InterceptAspectAnnotation {
}
```

So when i annotate my testcase in my project i get the sysout in the right places. 
But when i create my jar and bundle it in another project it don't do anything.

My pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>InterceptCall</artifactId>
<groupId>testing</groupId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>    
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only address your second question, so I will leave the first for others.

If you supply the aspect via an external library (like your built jar), you need to tell the aspectj-maven-plugin where to find the aspects to use for weaving. The **configuration**-tag needs to contain a tag called **aspectLibraries** with **aspectLibrary**-tags for each lib to use:

```
        <aspectLibraries>
           <aspectLibrary>
              <groupId>com.your.example.util</groupId>
              <artifactId>tracing-aspect</artifactId>
           </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
```

Comment: Hmm, I want to create a generic library with aspects that should be available for any project. So if you are right(need to check it out) it means that any project that wants to use my framework need to have aspectLibraries tag in their maven project? And if they use groovy or ant something similar for their build script.

Comment: Yes, no matter the build script, AspectJ needs to know which aspects to use for weaving. It can pick up everything that's part of the project's code any way, but if it comes as a library, that's not the case. Hence the aspectLibraries-tag.